# Beginner LaTeX error

Tags: math-mode, errors

I'm starting to write math equation on latex, so I tried it for the first time, but i cannot view the results due to an error. Can somebody help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\title{First doc latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
 $\sqrt{16} = 4$
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

at 1.7 there is an "?"
thx

Comment: please give titles that describe the problem. You begin `equation*` but end `equation`  delete the `*`  and remove the `$` you are already in `math`

Comment: Do you want an equation number or not?  If not, you can wrap it in `\[ ... \]` which is equivalent to the starred `equation`.

Answer (score 9):

You get

```
! Display math should end with $$.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.6  $\sqrt
           {16} = 4$
?
```

as `equation` has already started math so the `$` are in error.

Delete them and you get

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{equation*} on input line 5 ended by \end{equation}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.7 \end{equation}
                  
?
```

Because your `\begin` does not match `\end` so removing `*`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\title{First doc latex}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
 \sqrt{16} = 4
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is that you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\title{First doc latex}
\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \begin{equation*}
        \sqrt{16} = 4
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```